# Common Lisp has a some function. How can I write some or any in elisp?

Tags: emacs, dictionary, elisp

An `any` function would evaluate a function (or predicate) on elements of a sequence, returning true if the predicate returns true for any element of the sequence.  Therefore

```
(any `stringp `(42 t "yes" nil))
```

..would return non-nil, and

```
(any `stringp `(42 t nil 89))
```

...would return nil.

I think there is a `some` function in the CL module, but I don't want to use that.

It's easy to write a naive implementation using mapc:

```
(defun my-any (predicate sequence)
  "Return true if PREDICATE is true of any element of SEQUENCE.
If so, return the first non-nil value returned by PREDICATE.
"
  (let (result)
    (mapc '(lambda (elt)
             (or result
                 (setq result (funcall predicate elt))))
          sequence)
    result))
```

But can anyone provide optimizations or improvements on this?  Is there a faster or cleaner or more idiomatic elisp way to do this? In particular what is the best way to stop mapping through the sequence when the first one fires?  I could "unroll" mapc, but is that the best way?

I think I could use a `catch` but that may actually cost more than it saves.

tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(defun any (pred list)
  (while (and list (not (funcall pred (car list))))
    (pop list))
  (car list))
```

Answer (score 2):

At the very least you could terminate early when the predicate is true. Something like below.

```
 (defun my-any (predicate sequence)
  "Return true if PREDICATE is true of any element of SEQUENCE.
If so, return the first non-nil value returned by PREDICATE.
"
  (catch 'looking
    (mapc '(lambda (elt)
             (if (funcall predicate elt) (throw 'looking t)))
          sequence)
    nil))
```

Comment: As far as catch-throw costing more than it saves, that depends on how long your lists are.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use `find-if`, described at http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node145.html

It sounds like it does exactly what you want

```
(find-if 'stringp '(a "yes"))
"yes"
(find-if 'stringp '(a b))
nil
```